# How do I write folder-agnostic shell script on Mac as I can do in Windows?

Tags: command-line, bash, script

I would like to write a set of shell scripts which would execute smoothly on Mac disregarding where they are called from.

I am currently struggling about how to implement this.

On windows, I could write three batch scripts

`A.bat` in folder A
`B.bat` in folder `Subfolder`, which is subfolder of `A` and which path is `A/Subfolder`
`C.bat` in folder `Subfolder`, which is subfolder of `A` and which path is `A/Subfolder`

In `A.bat` I could write

```
call Subfolder/B.bat
```

in `B.Bat` I could write

```
call C.bat
```

and both scripts `A` and `B` would execute successfully.

On Mac, however, I have to prepend `./` to every script so that it is recognized as script.

So when I write in `a.sh` code:

```
Subfolder/b.sh
```

and then in `b.sh` code

```
./c.sh
```

when I execute `./b.sh` from terminal it is executed successfully.

However, when I execute `./a.sh` from a parent folder in terminal, it fails with error

> ```
> ./a.sh
> Subfolder/b.sh: line 1: ./c.sh: No such file or directory
> ```

Is this possible on Mac to write a code in b.sh which would execute disregarding if it is called from the current folder or from the parent folder?

Comment: "I would like to write a set of shell scripts which would execute smoothly on Mac disregarding where they are called from." I've tried this countless times, and there be dragons. I recommend just using Ruby or Python instead.

Comment: That‘s easily possible, eg by dynamically adding the required directory to PATH, by cd‘ing into the subfolder from a before calling b, and probably by a lot of other means.

Comment: "On Mac, however, I have to prepend ./ to every script so that it is recognized as script."  I wouldn't say this "so that it is recognized as script." The ./ isn't saying your invoking a script. It's providing a path to the file. If it was saying it was a script, you wouldn't need to say it's a executable file via chmod.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two concepts relevant to understand what's going on here:

- when running binaries or shell scripts as `name-of-executable`, the shell looks into `$PATH` for the list of directories the binary/shell script could be stored it. The first match found is then used to run the binary/script, if no match is found you get an error message. If instead you run it as `./name-of-executable` or `/path/to/executable` `$PATH` is not searched but the path is taken either relative to the current directory (if it starts with `./` or `../`) or absolute
- each process (including each shell script) has a default directory it runs in and which gets inherited to any child processes started

So in your case if you run `./a.sh` the current directory remains the one `a.sh` is stored in even when `subfolder/b.sh` is running, which then lets `./c.sh` fail.

The easy way out of this to always change directories before calling child processes (and of course changing back afterwards). So in `a.sh` you would write

```
cd subfolder
./b.sh
cd ..
```

which would allow `b.sh` to call `./c.sh` within the same subfolder without problems.

Comment: I didn't think about changing folder, I think it should work

Answer (score 1):

I'll claim there are three relevant concepts you are (/may be) running into trouble with here:

- In a unix-style shell, when you use a command name that doesn't include a "/", it's looked for in the directories in the `PATH` environment variable (places like /bin, /usr/bin, etc), not anyplace relative to where you are (or some current script is). On the other hand, if it does contain a "/", it's treated as a path for the command/script to run. Using `./` in front of a script name is just a way of specifying a path to a file in the current directory.
- In unix (including macOS), when you specify a relative path (to a document, script, or whatever), it's resolved relative to the process's current working directory; in a script, this is generally *not* the directory the script is in, but the directory the user (or whatever) was in when it ran the script.

  So if you're in /Users/patlatus and you run a script in /Users/patlatus/Documents/scriptproject, and the script refers to `Subfolder/b.sh`, it'll look for /Users/patlatus/Subfolder/b.sh. Finding files relative to the script is tricky, and not always possible (or even well-defined), but bash you can usually derive it from `$BASH_SOURCE`. Something like this:

  ```
  scriptdir=$(dirname "$BASH_SOURCE")    # Find the current script's directory
  "$scriptdir/Subfolder/b.sh"            # Run a script in a subdirectory of that
  ```
- When you run a script just with its path (or name), it'll run as a subprocess. This means it inherits copies of any variables exported from the parent script, but not unexported variables, and any changes it makes to variables will not propagate back to the parent script's shell. This is different from how `call` works in a batch script; `call` is closer to running another script with the `source` command (or its synonym `.`), which runs it in the same shell process (with full access to variables etc). If you want this, use the `.` or `source` command:

  ```
  scriptdir=$(dirname "$BASH_SOURCE")    # Find the current script's directory
  . "$scriptdir/Subfolder/b.sh"          # Source a script in a subdirectory of that
  ```

  Note that since the sourced script shares variables, if it redefines `scriptdir` as *its* directory, that'll affect its value in the calling script as well.
  Note that the `.` command has nothing whatsoever to do with the "." in `./scriptname` -- that's just a relative path starting from the current directory, not a command.